# Selecting multiple records with the max datestamp in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, greatest-n-per-group

This is the latest: one subquery to select all records before the specified date that match my criteria and then trying to group the results by userid and ordering by rank

It didn't seem to work tho. Please note that also there may be multiple people in the same rank.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT users.userid as userid,
               users.name as name,
               leagues.league as league,
               leagues.datestamp AS datestamp,
               ranking.ranking as ranking,
               user_profiles.profile_pic as profile_pic,
               user_profiles.team as team
          FROM users
     LEFT JOIN leagues ON users.userid = leagues.userid
     LEFT JOIN ranking ON users.userid = ranking.userid
     LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON users.userid=user_profiles.userid
         WHERE (leagues.datestamp <= '{$date}' 
           AND leagues.ladder = '3'  
           AND ranking.ladder = '3')
      ORDER BY datestamp DESC) as t1
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY ranking
```

Comment: On a side note, very much not a fan of including single quotes around numeric values and forcing MySQL to cast those strings to numbers. Sometimes that doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: U don't need ORDER BY datestamp DESC in the Sub query...

Comment: Do you want to find the maximum datestamp across all leagues, or the maximum datestamp per league?

Comment: Within league 3, I want to find all records that have the maximum datestamp BEFORE $date and only records that have the maximum datestamp then ordered by rank - all without executing any pointless queries... if that makes any sense

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a simple subquery?

```
SELECT users.userid as userid,
       users.name as name,
       leagues.league as league,
       leagues.datestamp AS datestamp,
       ranking.ranking as ranking,
       user_profiles.profile_pic as profile_pic,
       user_profiles.team as team
FROM   users
LEFT JOIN leagues ON users.userid = leagues.userid
LEFT JOIN ranking ON users.userid = ranking.userid
LEFT JOIN user_profiles ON users.userid=user_profiles.userid
WHERE  leagues.datestamp = (
    SELECT MAX(datestamp)
    FROM   leagues
    WHERE  leagues.ladder = '3'
      AND  leagues.datestamp <= '{$date}'
)
  AND  leagues.ladder = '3'  
  AND  ranking.ladder = '3'
ORDER BY ranking
```

Comment: thanks for that but noticed a fundamental problem with my LEFT JOINs